# Calculate next point on 2d linear vector

Tags: java, math, vector, path, 2d

I am pretty sure this can be solved by some basic trigonometry equations but unfortunately I cant figure it out.

What I need is:

[image: how to find next point on linear vector path 2d]

Given the x,y coordinates of two points in 2d I need to find the *next* point on the vector from one point towards another. Basically finding the closest linear path.

For example: on the image above we are given two points, we want to get from blue point to red point moving along path, therefore we need to find the next (gray point) each step until we reach it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you need to get the slope http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope

Comment: Do you just need to find the points between two given point? Then the Bresenham's algorithm is what you want. Although if you plan to render it in Java you'd better stick to internal Java implementation (that would be hardware accelerated). If you have to color the dots according to some algorithm (anti-alias?) then it could be more complicated, but again better use internal Java functions. So advise if you need to render it or develop an algorithm

Comment: I need it to move an image along the line, therefore I need the algorithm. I am already looking the Bresenham's solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your advice! I finally figured that out.
Here's a basic Java implementation of a method that finds the next point of the linear vector (assuming that we are moving 1 point per step)

```
  public int[] getNextLinePoint(int x,int y,int x2, int y2) {
    int w = x2 - x;
    int h = y2 - y;
    int dx1 = 0, dy1 = 0, dx2 = 0, dy2 = 0;
    if (w<0) dx1 = -1; else if (w>0) dx1 = 1;
    if (h<0) dy1 = -1; else if (h>0) dy1 = 1;
    if (w<0) dx2 = -1; else if (w>0) dx2 = 1;
    int longest = Math.abs(w);
    int shortest = Math.abs(h);
    if (!(longest>shortest)) {
        longest = Math.abs(h);
        shortest = Math.abs(w);
        if (h<0) dy2 = -1; else if (h>0) dy2 = 1;
        dx2 = 0;            
    }
    int numerator = longest >> 1;
    numerator += shortest;
    if (!(numerator<longest)) {
        numerator -= longest;
        x += dx1;
        y += dy1;
    } else {
        x += dx2;
        y += dy2;
    }
    int[] res = {x, y};
    return res;
}
```

This code returns the next x,y coordinates in a form of a 2-element int[] array.
Thanks again everybody!